# Convert Objective C code in swift 4

Tags: swift

how to convert Objective C Code in swift

```
NSString *responseString = [mtSCRALib getResponseData];
NSData *responseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"enc://%@", [^] [responseData base64Encoding]];
```

i Have tried this

```
var responseString = self.mtSCRALib.getResponseData()
var responseData: Data? = responseString?.data(using: .ascii)
```

but i dont know how to convert third line

Comment: The third line is not valid Objective-C.

Comment: Are you using this one https://www.swipebox.io/integration/wiki/developers-guide/e2e/

Comment: @MartinR i am using USAePay library for payment https://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/endtoendencryption. and library code is in objective c.

Comment: I am not familiar with that library, but unless I am overlooking something, the `[^]` makes no sense.

Comment: @PranavanSp yes similar library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the third line:

```swift
if let responseData = responseString?.data(using: .ascii) {
    let encodedString = "enc://\(responseData.base64EncodedString())"
    // print(encodedString)
}
```

You'll need to check if `responseData` is not `nil` before using it – that's what the `if let ... = ...` is for.

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
let encodedString = "enc://\(responseData.base64EncodedData())"
```

Hope it may help you.